# How to stop Hangman python program when the user has guessed the correct words?

Tags: python, loops

I'm making a simple hangman program using while-loops. The program that I've written works, but I don't know how to make it stop once the user has guessed the correct letters.

Here is what I have so far:

```
word = input("What's the secret word? ")
lives = int(input("Amount of lives? "))

while True:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    if guess in word:
        print("Correct, the letter is in the secret word.")
    else:
        lives -= 1
        print(f"The letter {guess} is not in the secret word.")
        if lives > 0:
            print(f"You have {lives} lives left, try again.")
        else:
            print("You have no lives left.")
            break
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to keep track of the `set` of letters already guessed?

Comment: In your input, you want to check the number of unique characters in the word. You'll need to have a list that has the persons guesses and check if all of the letters in the set are in the list then end the loop.

Comment: Adding a break in if will stop the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I see is to add some counter of correctly guessed letters, so you can reason when the word itself is guessed correctly.

```
guessed_so_far = 0
already_guessed = []
while True:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    if guess in word and guess not in already_guessed:
        print("Correct, the letter is in the secret word.")
        guessed_so_far += 1
        already_guessed.append(guess)
    if guessed_so_far == len(set(word)):
        break
```

As Joshua correctly suggested, you have to compare with `len(set(word))`

Comment: Thanks, @JoshuaVoskamp for pointing out bugs.
Had to think hard, not fast :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `guess = input(...)` code has a subtle bug: what if the user inputs a `len(guess) > 1` string? Ignoring that possibility for a moment:

```py
word = input("What's the secret word? ")
letters = set(word)

...

# if the guess (assumed single character) is in the set of letters
if guess in letters:
    print("Correct, the letter is in the secret word.")
    
    # reduce the set of letters remaining by the current guess
    letters = letters - set(guess)

    # if there aren't any letters left to guess
    if len(letters) == 0:
        print("Congrats! You won!")
        break
```